# REST APIs on Meteor with OAuth2.0 authentication

Tags: rest, web-services, meteor, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have developed a centralized users database on Meteor and exposed the end points via REST APIs.
Everything is going perfect so far.

I used following package for REST APIs with Meteor:

```
nimble:restivus
```

Now I need to apply OAuth2.0 authentication on those end points.

Can anyone recommend the best package for Meteor that is nicely compatible?